# XenServer pool, unable to access certain networks from 2 servers in pool

Tags: linux, virtualization, xenserver

I have Xenserver pool of of 3 xenservers, at version 6.1. After we got a serious DDOS attack on our network, all servers got rebooted (whole pool of 3 servers got restart and entered into maintenance mode). After which, one of the server (Master) kept working fine, but on rest of 2 slaves, i am unable to properly connect to some networks (WAN and LAN), except SAN, which is also facing intermittent delays. Sometime i am able to ping VM's WAN IPs, but sometimes it doesnt. 
What could be the reason for this?

Also, 2 of the affected servers keep crashing 1-2 times in a day, just at any time.

Hope  someone can guide me that what could be the reason for this problem.

I am thinking of re-building whole pool from scratch.